# Homestead not loading the page (symfony)

Tags: symfony, vagrant, symfony4, homestead

I am working on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.2. I am quite new to vagrant and this would be my first project in Symfony. I set up the environment to start my first symfony 4 project. Everything was installed correctly (including VirtualBox, Vagrant). I updated my hosts file, I edited Homestead.yaml and at the end when I wanted to access my domain (symf01.test) in Chrome I get a message that this site can't be reached and a text file is downloaded automatically, containing such information:

```
<?php    
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';
if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) { unmask(0000);
Debug::enable();}
if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) 
{   Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);}
if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) 
{   Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);}
$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
ip:"192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: /Users/username/Homestead/code/simba
  to: /home/vagrant/simba
  type: "nfs"

sites:
- map: symf01.test
  to: /home/vagrant/simba/public
  type: symfony

databases:
- homestead

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# zray:
#  If you've already freely registered Z-Ray, you can place the token here.
#     - email: foo@bar.com
#       token: foo
#  Don't forget to ensure that you have 'zray: "true"' for your site.
```

This is what I get when I run serve nginx status[image]

Comment: Hello @shark123, downloading an .php file is an indicative that your server or doesn't have php installed or it is not fully configured. Have you checked that?

Comment: Can you please show us your `Homestead.yaml` file?

Comment: @leoap here is what I did so far:@leoap here is what I did so far:  I installed vagrant, virtualbox. I added laravel/homestead box.  I cloned laravel homestead repository to my Homestead directory and initialized homestead. I edited my Homestead.yaml file accordingly as well as hosts file. I run vagrant up command and I created a symfony project via composer in my project folder. I think it should be fully configured.

Comment: @Domagoj I posted a yaml file below.

Comment: What happens if you `ping symf01.test` ? 
Also, please just edit your first post with all the relevant info, no need to add it as answers - moderators might remove it.

Comment: Another idea, try setting `type: "symfony4"` in your `Homestead.yaml`

Comment: @Domagoj thank you ! It worked! After one week of struggling finally I got to install symfony :) I am the happiest person on the earth right now :)

Comment: @shark123 No problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this helped:

```
...
sites:
- map: symf01.test
  to: /home/vagrant/simba/public
  type: symfony
```

to

```
...
sites:
- map: symf01.test
  to: /home/vagrant/simba/public
  type: "symfony4"
```

Difference is in syntax. Value of `type` needs to be under quotes. 
That `type` tells Homestead how to modify `.htaccess` files so that your websites can be properly accessed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Domagoj !

Comment: @shark123 No problem. You can click the check mark near the answer to mark it as accepted so that if anyone else encounters the same problem, the solution is clear and visible.